# Computer freeze at night

Tags: windows-7, freeze

Every night except one this week my laptop froze over night.
I tried to check the event viewer, but there's no real help there.
Tonight I'll do a memtest to check the RAM.
And this shouldn't be a temperature issue since I can play game without any problem (Diablo 3, League of legend)
Is there any diagnosys tool I could use. Maybe something that would write time down every minute so I know the precise time when it freeze?
I have win7 and 8gb of RAM I installed myself

Answer to comment:Asus N71JQ
Unknown time, but it seems differents if I look at the last entry in the logs
I have no information to tell you, that's why I ask for tool and not the solution.
I usualy go to sleep after midnight, but I have AVG free edition as antivirus
I'll try the IRC thing since I'm not much of a computer programmer thanks.
It only started this week, so longuest maybe 2 weeks, shortest 1 day. And this week there was a day were it didn't free.
On AC the laptop shouldn't ever go to sleep or hibernation (hibernation is also deactivated). But on battery its 10 minute. But overnight the AC is plugged in and the battery is there also. I'll try to put it in sleep tomorrow night and see.

New: I did the windows memory diagnostic tool, and it didn't detect any problem. But when it rebooted, it told me it couldn't detect an hard drive to boot with. Shutting it down and powering it on went well after. I checked and both drive are well connected and are now working, SMART doesn't report an error.

Comment: Make and model of laptop?

Comment: Same times? Event log events? What kind of freeze?

Comment: You need to come back AFTER you have attempt to figure out the problem. We cannot help you unless you bring information to the table.  If your computer is freezing it normally indicates a HARDWARE problem.

Comment: Any program/antivirus scheduled to run midnight everyday?

Comment: One 'hack' i use to work out the time a computer shuts down is to join an IRC channel, have another system on the same channel and note the time it pings out. There's probably a neater way to do it though.

Comment: You could write a simple little Java (or whatever) program to write to a file (and flush) once a minute or so.

Comment: What is the longest it's gone without crashing?  What is the shortest interval it's crashed in?  (Based on when you went to bed and got up, etc.)

Comment: What is the laptop set up to do when unattended -- how soon is it supposed to sleep?  Is is supposed to sleep or hibernate?

Comment: I suspect one of two problems:  1) The system is getting "confused" when trying to sleep/hibernate and ends up crashing.  2) The battery charger is detecting a fault (overvoltage/overcharge) and killing power.  Try running overnight (sleeping) on battery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I exchanged the 2 drive to each other slot and there was no problem in 2 days.

Answer (score 0):

Asus offers a system monitor and an update utility that may assist.  This link is for Win7 64 Bit [Asus Support](http://support.asus.com/download.aspx?SLanguage=en&p=3&s=225&m=N71Jq&os=&hashedid=hUn2kMS4sU3z3kUV)

Comment: Updates there are all 2 years old, and the system monitor isn't helpfull. It only tells about S.M.A.R.T. data and that temperature are ok

Answer (score 0):

You might want to take a look at the System (or even the Application) logs on your computer to get an answer on why it may be hanging up.  You can find the logs by right clicking on "Computer" and selecting "Manage".  After that you can check out the "Event Viewer".  (If you are already looking at the logs, then disregard this section.  I wasn't sure if you said you were looking at the System logs in your OP)

As far as a suggestion for your problem...I have seen documented issues of computers with large hard drives (1TB+) crashing or freezing when the user attempts to wake it up due to a driver that determines if it takes too long to boot up the drive it should just fail instead.  Perhaps this is your case

Comment: No, 1 60gb SSD and an 360GB HDD

Answer (score 0):

As far as the "Couldn't detect an hard drive to boot with" problem is concern try any of following.

- If you system drive(HDD on which os is installed) is connected with SATA cable, try replacing existing new SATA cable.
- If any of you HDD have jumper setting then, if system drive has jumper set it to Primary, else set it to slave.(Generally this setting can be found on HDD sticker)

Now for the system frezzing problem, try to check hard disk sleep time. If you have specified the time try to disable it. This might solve your problem.